# Deserialize field to HashMap<String, MyStruct>

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I have a TOML file like this:

```ini
[versions."4.2-stable"]
path = "..."

[versions."3.5-rc3"]
path = "..."

# etc.
```

And a struct like this:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct Versions {
    pub versions: SomeMapType<String, Version>,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct Version {
    pub path: String,
}
```

I want to be able to deserialize that TOML into my struct, but the problem is that i'm not sure what type to use in place of `SomeMapType`. I tried using `ahash::AHashMap` and `toml::map::Map`, but neither worked and result in " doesn't implement Deserialize" errors. Maybe some custom logic is needed? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think `std::collections::HashMap` should work.

Comment: Working code on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=427cb953da0bc7ddcc2a69456567b528

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you! Your answer helped me find out that ahash actually has a `serde` feature that makes `AHashMap` work!